# Jquery Ajax autocomplete syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been staring at this function for way to long, my eyes beg for help.
The data is flowing correctly but does not pop up for autocomplete.

```
function LookUp(InputBox) {
    $( "#JobCodeInput" ).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ApplicationReview/JobCodeLedgerDeptLookUp",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { SearchString: $(InputBox).val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.length);
                    response($.map(data, function (job) {
                        return {
                            label: job.JobSearch,
                            value: job.JobCode
                        };
                    }));
                }
            })
        }
    });
}
```

The length is showing the correct numbers, and if i add an alert in the response($.map function i get each job with their properties but alas no autocomplete still.

EDIT1: My controller is converting to json and i can see the proper json in the response.

EDIT2: I have an input field with an onchange event calling LookUp, that call is working correctly.

EDIT3: If i console.log(data) i get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` return within your success handler?

Comment: 1. Are you getting an error? 2. Did you call LookUp()?

Comment: where do you call t he function `LookUp`?

Comment: I call the lookup on an input onchange event, which was working before i moved from a hard coded array to a ajax call.

Comment: Remove the function LookUp(); you don't need it. run your code onready or any other way

Comment: Have you looked at the [remote data source](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) option associated with the autocomplete widget. It looks like it handles the ajax request internally. Simply return the properly formatted array of values and it should work.

Comment: Don't make the ajax synchronous unless you have a VERY good reason to do so.

Comment: I don't see any reason to make it synchronous, i think the entire issue is the autocomplete method. I must be doing something wrong there.

Comment: Again, can you show `console.log(data)`?

Comment: @Mike Brant my console.log shows  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

add this script

```
$(function() {
  LookUp("#input-box-id")
});
```

Comment: The function is being called correctly, i think the issue is with the autocomplete part.

Comment: i forgot that alert has been execute